# problema con php y mysqal $pdo

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, web, pdo

este codigo es un carpeta subcarpeta de nombre config.php de mismo proyecto

```html
<?php
define('SERVIDOR','localhost');
define('USUARIO','root');
define('PASSWORD','$J91p0324$');
define('BD','sisfarmacia');

$URL = 'http://localhost/www.sisfarmacias.com';

$servidor = "mysql:dbname=" .BD. ";host=" .SERVIDOR;


try {

    $pdo = new PDO($servidor, USUARIO, PASSWORD, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>"SET NAMES utf8"));
        echo "<script>alert('La conexion a la base de datos fue exitosa.')</script>";
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch (PDOException $e) {

    echo "<script>alert('Error a la conexion con la base de datos.')</script>";

} finally {

    $pdo=null;
}

?>
```

y es llamado desde otro subcarpeta de nombre controller.php la cual con el metodo include se trata de llamar a config.php

```html
<?php

include ('../app/config/config.php');




$nombres = $_POST['nombres'];
$apellido1 = $_POST['apellido1'];
$apellido2 = $_POST['apellido2'];
$cc = $_POST['cc'];
$fecha_nacimiento = $_POST['fecha_nacimiento'];
$pais = $_POST['pais'];
$celular = $_POST['celular'];
$codigo_postal = $_POST['codigo_postal'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$cargo = $_POST['cargo'];

$user_creacion = "jposso@ut.edu.co";
date_default_timezone_set("America/Bogota");
$fechaHora = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
$estado = '1';

try{

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tb_usuarios 
    (nombres, apellido1, apellido2, cc, fecha_nacimiento, pais, celular, codigo_postal,
     email, password, cargo, user_creacion, fyh_creacion, estado) 

    VALUES (:nombres, :apellido1, :apellido2, :cc, :fecha_nacimiento, :pais, :celular, :codigo_postal,
        :email, :password, :cargo, :user_creacion, :fyh_creacion, :estado)");


$stmt->bindParam(':nombres', $nombres);
$stmt->bindParam(':apellido1', $apellido1);
$stmt->bindParam(':apellido2', $apellido2);
$stmt->bindParam(':cc', $cc);
$stmt->bindParam(':fecha_nacimiento', $fecha_nacimiento);
$stmt->bindParam(':pais', $pais);
$stmt->bindParam(':celular', $celular);
$stmt->bindParam(':codigo_postal', $codigo_postal);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
$stmt->bindParam(':cargo', $cargo);
$stmt->bindParam(':user_creacion', $user_creacion);
$stmt->bindParam(':fyh_creacion', $fechaHora);
$stmt->bindParam(':estado', $estado);

$stmt->execute();

echo "<script>alert('Registro exitoso.')</script>";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    // Manejar el error de la base de datos aquí
    echo "Error en la inserción de datos: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

pero cuando se ejecuta en la pagina web sale un error en la linar del (45) donde se encuentra $stmt->execute() que el encargado de ejecutarse y el error es: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\www.sisfarmacias.com\usuarios\controller_create.php:25 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\www.sisfarmacias.com\usuarios\controller_create.php on line 25; además que el editor de código hay un error: líneas (22) donde esta $pdo donde indica Undefined variable '$pdo' el cual no entiendo por indica que no ha sido definida la variable si en la subcarpeta config.php así declarada en el try de la conexión a la base de datos me podrían ayudar gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: hay un error, pero el editor esta echo para php8 con clases no para el que estas usando, por lo que te marca error, el editor no comprende los include, ademas el problema es el pdo que no esta definiendose, uede que el include no apunte correctamente

Comment: Tú mismo estás poniendo la variable $pdo a null en tu finally. Luego está lo que apunta John, si el propio editor no te reconoce la variable no es buena señal tampoco. Y si pones una captura de pantalla que salga el error y la línea donde se produce. Ninguna de esas dos cosas se ven.